# Val() return object instead of string when using it as parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameters, return

I have the following line of code:

```
var show = new Show(artist.val(), day.val(), starttime.val(), endtime.val());
```

My problem is that my show object contains the objects after this line, not the value I'm trying to get with val():

> [image: The object in debugger]

How do I make sure to get the value instead of the object? I already tried this:

```
var artistvalue = artist.val();
var show = new Show(artistvalue, day.val(), starttime.val(), endtime.val());
```

Still, the shows artist field says input#artist.text.... etc.

Comment: Add your `HTML code` please

Comment: Is `artist` a JQuery selector ? If they are JQuery object, its normal that .val() return the object and not the value contained. If so, use .html() to get the value. Also, as @Misters has noticed, using `.val()` on a select element does'nt return the selected value.

Comment: @TCHdvlp see carefully, they are all inputs and select

Comment: should be `var artistvalue = $('#artist').val();` etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out what was wrong, it was not in the code that I provided here, but in the declaration of Show():

```
function Show(){
    this.artist = artist;
    this.day = day;
    this.starttime = starttime;
    this.endtime = endtime;
}
```

Show was missing it's parameters, so it just used artist, etc from the other function. Changing it to the following helped:

```
function Show(artist, day, starttime, endtime){
    this.artist = artist;
    this.day = day;
    this.starttime = starttime;
    this.endtime = endtime;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use this, as artist is a jquery seletcor

```
 $(artist).val()
```

instead of

```
 artist.val()
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('[name="artist"]').val();
```

or

```
$('[name="artist"]').text();
```

assuming name of element is artist

Answer (score 0):

You should try `$("#artist").val()` if artist is the id of the field
or, `$("[name='artist']").val()` if artist is the name of the field